# Web based election database software

Tags: web-applications, voting

I was wondering if there is any web based election database open source project out there that:

- Could be customised to match every countrie's election system (all elections: presidential, general, regional, ...)
- Helps keeping track of all the candidates with their programs and promises during and after the election
- Every candidate or elected member has a section for all infos related to him during his mandate for example, plus a discussion forum...
- ...

And so on... Something that can hold everything related to a democratic and political system of a given country and which is community-powered of course...

I hope you get the idea (I couldn't explain better... Feel free to edit to add more details)

So, does any open source project doing almost all of the above exists ?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could take a look at this webpage:

https://vote.heliosvoting.org/

or

http://web-based-election-software.soft112.com/

It seems they can do what you are asking for and it is opensource....

Hope it helps...